# Infile replacement empties the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I was trying to replace some lines of html inplace

But it is resulting in empty file .

I'm checking if line has a particular string and trying to replace it

```
with fileinput.FileInput(bmark_file, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file :
        unique="id="+core
        if unique in line:
            print(line.replace(link['href'], vboard[core.lower()]['benchmarks.tls']), end='')
```

Actually infile module should not empty the file even if condition fails

Any inputs on this will be helpful

Comment: Nothing in this code should empty the file.  That must happen in some other code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Minor side-note: `core` never changes in this code. You should probably define `unique` above the `for` loop, just to avoid recreating the same string on every loop.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *only* `print`ing when your test passes, so any line that doesn't pass the test doesn't end up in the new file (`FileInput` with `inplace=True` replaces the original file with whatever you emit to `sys.stdout`; if you don't emit anything, it doesn't write anything). If you want the other lines to pass unchanged, you need to output the original line in the `else` case:

```
with fileinput.FileInput(bmark_file, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file :
        unique="id="+core
        if unique in line:
            print(line.replace(link['href'], vboard[core.lower()]['benchmarks.tls']), end='')
        else:
            print(line, end='')  # Or just sys.stdout.write(line)
```

The fact that your file ended up empty implies that the `unique in line` test never passed, so you may be expecting non-existent data.

Comment: But now I have another issue , If the file "bmark_file" in the code is a soflink , this code removes the softlink . Any inputs on this will be really helpful

Comment: @Ganga: In general, you should really ask a separate question on that. In this case, the answer is pretty simple though; wrap `bmark_file` in [`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) to have `FileInput` work on the target of the symlink, not the symlink itself.